# set data in service from run and notify all controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am loading data in `.run` of angular app, my problem, I want to use data in different controller , but Ajax may take time to load data. Is there any way to hold the controller or notify controller so that controller can get data from service instead of `$http`.

```
listingApp.run(['ListingData', '$http','$q', function (ListingData, $http,$q) {
      // // make the api request here
       var listing_def = $q.defer();
       $http.get('/api/products/7569356/').then(function (result) {

             ListingData.setData(result);
              listing_def.resolve(data);
          });
      return listing_def.promise;

    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

example:

```
angular.module('test', [])  // Not testet
.run(function($http, $q, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.loadData = (loadDefer = $q.defer()).promise

    $http.get('url').then(function(result) {
        loadDefer.resolve(result);
    })
})
.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.loadData.then(function(result) {
         console.log(result);
     });
});
```

Comment: do u have any sample fiddle , m not able to understand where loadDefer is used ?

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d14nLuv0/) the result is empty, but you see how it works..., take a look at the console